# Apollo client userQuery onError is no longer executing

Tags: apollo-client

We upgraded from @apollo/client 3.7.2 to 3.8.2

When we did that, it seems the onError in useQuery no longer executes when it receives GraphQLErrors.

If we add a errorPolicy: "all" to the query, it will execute.

But it does not feel like a solution... Any ideas what may be causing this?